# Atom Plotly, Pandas_datareader

Tags: python, plotly, pandas-datareader

I have Python 3.7.4 and Atom 1.40.1. I created virtual environment and installed plotly and pandas_datareader, but I cannot import it. Is there any additional step I should make or I am doing something wrong? tnx